# QtCreator Cannot open include file (Windows)

Tags: windows, qt, opencv, eigen, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a open source project on windows: https://github.com/francisengelmann/FabScan100

I am using QtCreator 2.7.0, Qt Qt5.0.2 msvc2010_opengl, MSVC2010

My direcotries look like this:

```
C:\
C:\libs\opencv-2.4.2\
C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0
C:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.2
C:\fabscan\FabScan100-master
```

I modified the qtTest.pro file to include the neccessary headers and libs:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include
LIBS += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\bin

INCLUDEPATH += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\FLANN\include\flann
LIBS += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\FLANN\lib

INCLUDEPATH += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost
LIBS += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib

INCLUDEPATH += C:\libs\opencv-2.4.2\opencv\build\include
LIBS += C:\libs\opencv-2.4.2\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib


INCLUDEPATH += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6
LIBS += C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\lib \
-lpcl_common \
-lpcl_io \
-lpcl_filters \
-lpcl_kdtree \
-lpcl_registration \
-lpcl_features \
-lpcl_segmentation \
-lpcl_surface \
-lpcl_search
```

But when I press the compile button QtCreator throws me an error:

```
..\qtTest\staticHeaders.h(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Eigen/Core': No such file or directory
```

Which is kind of strange because the file is actually there. I am also able to open it in QtCreator by pressing STRG & Clicking on the include statement in staticHeaders.h

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put the Eigen library path into LIBS, or also its parent? Note that the code tries to include _Engine_/Core, and not Core. If you only include _Eigen_ and not its parent, it will not work. Can you make sure please?

Comment: @LaszloPapp in the INCLUDE directory (C:\libs\eigen-3.0.5\include) is a directory "Eigen" which contains the file "Core" (without a extenstion). I guess thats ok? But in the LIBS directory (C:\libs\eigen-3.0.5\bin) there are only two DLL files (msvcp100.dll & msvcr100.dll) - not *.lib files like the other LIB directories :-/

Comment: Based on the staticHeaders.h code (line 4), you need to have a folder called "Eigen" which contains the "Core" file. Do you have a folder called like that inside the eigen lib parent somewhere down the line? For instance, I have this on Linux: /usr/include/eigen2/Eigen/Core in which case /usr/include/eigen2 has to be added to the LIB variable with qmake. Do you have an "Eigen" folder in "C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include"?

Comment: Ok. Punch me for stupidity. I thougt saving the *.pro file & pressing build is all I have to do. Recently discovered this magic "execure qmake" button. As far as I understand this, I have to click that button to recreate the make file(s) after making a change in the *.pro file

Comment: Reini, OK, submitted an answer covering this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `staticHeaders.h` code (line 4), you need to have a folder called "Eigen" which contains the "Core" file. For instance, I have `/usr/include/eigen2/Eigen/Core` on Linux, in which case `/usr/include/eigen2` has to be added to the `INCLUDEPATH` variable with qmake. Make sure you have `C:\libs\pcl-1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include`.

Also, if it does not work in QtCreator as per your comment, you can always try to force explicitly to rerun qmake by the `execute qmake` option.

Comment: Thanks. Also found out, that Eigen is a header only library which doesn't come with any neccessary libs - so a modification to LIBS is not neccessary at all

Comment: @Reini: Yes, you are right. I meant to write INCLUDEPATH, sorry. :)